# PHP CLI Application on Debian: why can't I output a line break?

Tags: php, debian, echo, command-line-interface, line-breaks

I have a really puzzling problem: I am writing a PHP CLI application running on a debian server. I am connected to the server via SSH, just the normal way. Everything runs as usual. Except the following:

```
echo "My CLI fun\n\n";
echo "Is this.";
```

Outputs on the SSH terminal, when executing the PHP script:

```
My CLI funIs this.
```

I am really puzzled as I have never had such a problem. The bash behaves normal in all other aspects. I already tried to output `chr(10)` and such, same problem.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: As a side note, if I pipe the output into a file, the file does not contain the newlines.

Comment: Another side note: spaces are stripped out, writing to STDOUT gives the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Sorry for wasting your time. The problem was that the php script was passed through a bash script that called it.

So, for people with the same problem: bash scripts seem to filter the output in some strange ways! Try calling the php script directly.

Comment: Just accept this answer instead of editing "Solved" into the title.

Comment: I can accept my own answer only after waiting 2 days. In the mean time, "[SOLVED]" might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem. Changing from a #!/bin/bash and executing the php file to #!/usr/bin/php5 <?php require('the file'); did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using PHP's OS-sensitive constant:

```
echo "My CLI fun".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL; 
echo "Is this.";
```

Comment: Tried that, did not work either. Another side note: if I echo "ABC             ABC", the spaces get stripped to a single space. I start wondering whether some strange output filter postprocesses the scripts output...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
echo "My CLI fun" . chr(13) . chr(10);
echo "Is this";
```

..?

I know it's kind of a MSWindows thing, but it works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is resolved now - it was a bash script problem. Sorry for wasting your effort...